# Docker Volume bind mount access is denied

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker volumes and I'm having trouble with bind mounts. I can't seem to bind my local repository because I keep getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Program Files\docker\dockerProject\jenkins: Access is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The command I'm running is `docker run --privileged=true --name myJenkins3 -v "C:\Program Files\docker\dockerProject/jenkins":/var/jenkins_home -p 9191:8080 -p 40000:50000 jenkins/jenkins`

Does anyone know why I'm getting access denied error when using the bind mount?

UPDATE: It looks like I'm able to run the command on mac without any issues, however issue is still occurring on windows.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you need to run in an administrator shell to mount volumes with Docker.

So right mouse on your shell and then select run as administrator. Then you can run Docker and mount your volumes.